# Debug Linux kernel pre-decompression stage

Tags: linux-kernel, gdb, embedded, arm

I am trying to use GDB to debug a Linux kernel zImage before it is decompressed. The kernel is running on an ARM target and I have a JTAG debugger connected to it with a GDB server stub. The target has to load a boot loader. The boot loader reads the kernel image from flash and puts it in RAM at `0x20008000`, then branches to that location.

I have started GDB and connected to the remote target, then I use GDB's `add-symbol-file` command like so:

```
add-symbol-file arch/arm/boot/compressed/vmlinux 0x20008000 -readnow
```

When I set a breakpoint for that address, it does trap at the correct place - right when it branches to the kernel. However, **GDB shows the wrong line from the source of `arch/arm/boot/compressed/head.S`. It's 4 lines behind. How can I fix this?**

I also have tried adding the `-s section addr` option to `add-symbol-file` with `-s .start 0x20008000`; this results in exactly the same problem.

Comment: First make sure you have a gcc and gdb that are compatible, preferably from the same toolchain version. Also, know that the Linux kernel is compiled with -O2 so some lines get optimized out. Are you you sure there isn't any .align keywords there somewhere?

Comment: The decompressor code is all PC relative.  It can even copy itself from one region to another.  The boot loader may put it where the decompressed target is; so it has to move itself.  I doubt that you are going to have good times using JTAG with fixed symbols.  I don't know if you can *relocate* with GDB somehow.

Comment: Seems to work fine for debugging decompression with Lauterbach T32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are assembler macros that print out stuff when compiling with *low level* debug.  You have to make sure the macros are appropriate for your board.

```
linux-latest/arch/arm$ find . -name debug-macro.S | wc
 56      56    2306
```

Find the file for your board and ensure the correct serial port registers are hit.  You can instrument the code with out using JTAG.  These macros are used in the decompress code.  Of course configure with *CONFIG_DEBUG_LL*.

Most likely the ATAGs are not correct or one of the other requirements.  Checkout *Documentation/arm/Booting* to make sure you have registers set properly.  Note there is a new requirement with recent kernels to send a **dt** list.

Comment: Current macros are in [arm include debug](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/include/debug) (as of Jan2015 v3.19).  Also see: [compressed debug.S](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/boot/compressed/debug.S)